# Redirect to external urls does not work in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, localhost

I'm kind of new to Laravel, when I try to redirect to an external URL I get a blank page. I running the Laravel on my local machine.

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('/pay', function () {
    
    return view('pay');
});
```

This is a code that I try to run inside pay.blade.php

```
return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');
```

Comment: Why redirect from inside a view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```php
redirect()->to('https://www.google.com')->send();
```

Comment: Works for me.  Have an up vote.